# How to omit vertical realignment when using cmidrule in different colors?

Tags: color, vertical-alignment, booktabs

My question is similar to the one here [How do I eliminate the vertical realignment when using arrayrulecolor with cmidrule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32362/) but can not be solved with the suggested answer (because the lines are trimmed).

I'd like to make a table with trimmed horizontal lines (as they can be generated by `\cmidrule` from package `booktabs`) but with changing colors.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\ \cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-1}\arrayrulecolor{blue}\cmidrule[2pt](lr){2-2}\arrayrulecolor{black}\cmidrule[2pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This does pretty much what I want but the horizontal lines are realigned vertically after every color change. How can I omit this realignment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can correct for this vertical re-alignment using the `\corcmidrule[<len>]` macro defined below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Correct for \cmidrule colour adjustment/vertical skip
\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][2pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
  \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{black}%
  \cmidrule[2pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
  \cmidrule[5pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule[5pt]\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
  \cmidrule[3pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule[3pt]\arrayrulecolor{orange}%
  \cmidrule[7pt](lr){3-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}​
```

The macro performs a traditional `tabular` line break `\\[<len>]` of specified length. The length is a correction taking into account the normal baseline skip `\normalbaselineskip`, the above/below rule skip enforced by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) called `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`, as well as a parameter specifying the `\cmidrule` width - default is `2pt` (by virtue of your MWE). Alternatively, if you have a rule of width (say) `5pt`, you could use `\corcmidrule[5pt]`, as was used in the second example.