# Special cmidrule with booktabs - colored and custom spacing with cmidrule

Tags: tables, booktabs

I would like to create a gray cmidrule a la booktabs. I have created a gray midrule `gmidrule` (extends entire table width) with different tighter space via

`\newcommand{\gmidrule{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0.4\aboverulesep}{0.6\belowrulesep}\arrayrulecolor{black}}`

Now, I would like to apply a light gray color, and identical separation as shown above, for a `cmidrule` (partial rule), and call this variation `gcmidrule`.

First issue is that the cmidrules are staggered. I would like to resolve this, but also adust the above and below rule sep.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\gmidrule}{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0.4\aboverulesep}{0.6\belowrulesep}\arrayrulecolor{black}}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\gcmidrule}{ O{} D(){} m }{%
    %% I would like to reduce the distance here as well, but the midrules are staggered
    \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}%
    \cmidrule{#3}%
    %  \cmidrule[#1](#2){#3}% supposed to be like this, but causes error. I'll worry about this later
    \arrayrulecolor{black}%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{lllll}\toprule
        a & b & c & d & e \\\gmidrule
        a & b & c & d & e \\\gcmidrule{1-2}\gcmidrule{4-5} % notice the stagger
        a & b & c & d & e \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Update**:

This question is slightly helpful in that it helps align the cmidrules, however it does not adjust the above and below sep: [How to omit vertical realignment when using cmidrule in different colors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35817/how-to-omit-vertical-realignment-when-using-cmidrule-in-different-colors)

```
%% added this
% Correct for \cmidrule colour adjustment/vertical skip
\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][0pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
  \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

%% add this in gcmidrule

\corcmidrule%
```

Still staggered, and adjusting the `[0pt]` still leaves staggered.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\cmidrule` is written in a way to check if more `\cmidrule`s follow it. If that is the case, it purposefully performs a vertical readjustment so the `\cmidrule`s follow on the same line. So using (say)

```
\gcmidrule[<A>](<B>){<C>}\gcmidrule[<D>](<E>){<F>}`
```

in your way would effectively translate to

```
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}% ----\
\cmidrule[<A>](<B>){<C>}%       | = First \gcmidrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}% --------/
\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}% ----\
\cmidrule[<D>](<E>){<F>}%       | = Second \gcmidrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}% --------/
```

While it's not incorrect to switch colours back-and-forth, the first `\cmidrule` just doesn't find that it is followed by another `\cmidrule`. Hence, there's no vertical correction.

The easiest way that makes the most sense is to copy the original definition(s) if `\cmidrule` (and subsidiary commands) and change them to show as `\gcmidrule` (and subsidiaries), including the "checking ahead" part.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\gmidrule}{%
  \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}%
  \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0.4\aboverulesep}{0.6\belowrulesep}%
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%
}

% Copy \cmidrule from
%  http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.dtx
% and modify it for insertion of \arrayrulecolor{lightgray} at the start,
% and \arrayrulecolor{black} at the end
\makeatletter
\def\gcmidrule{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}% Switch colour to lightgray
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@ifnextchar[{\@gcmidrule}{\@gcmidrule[\cmidrulewidth]}}
\def\@gcmidrule[#1]{\@ifnextchar({\@@gcmidrule[#1]}{\@@gcmidrule[#1]()}}
\def\@@gcmidrule[#1](#2)#3{\@@@gcmidrule[#3]{#1}{#2}}
\def\@@@gcmidrule[#1-#2]#3#4{\global\@cmidla#1\relax
    \global\advance\@cmidla\m@ne
    \ifnum\@cmidla>0\global\let\@gtempa\@cmidrulea\else
    \global\let\@gtempa\@cmidruleb\fi
    \global\@cmidlb#2\relax
    \global\advance\@cmidlb-\@cmidla
    \global\@thisrulewidth=#3
    \@setrulekerning{#4}
    \ifnum\@lastruleclass=\z@\vskip \aboverulesep\fi
    \ifnum0=`{\fi}\@gtempa
    \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\futurenonspacelet\@tempa\@xgcmidrule}
\def\@xgcmidrule{%
   \ifx\@tempa\gcmidrule
       \vskip-\@thisrulewidth
       \global\@lastruleclass=\@ne
   \else \ifx\@tempa\morecmidrules
       \vskip \cmidrulesep
       \global\@lastruleclass=\@ne\else
       \vskip \belowrulesep
       \global\@lastruleclass=\z@
   \fi\fi
   \ifnum0=`{\fi}
  \arrayrulecolor{black}}% Switch colour back to black
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
  \toprule
  a & b & c & d & e \\
  \gmidrule
  a & b & c & d & e \\
  \gcmidrule{1-2}\gcmidrule{4-5}
  a & b & c & d & e \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I wanted to change the space later, say 0.2\aboverulesep and 0.6\belowrulesep, how would I do so? It's not obvious in the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I will give a possible solution with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). You can also adjust `abovesep` and `belowsep` in a similar way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector { mainfive }
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2} {5} { \l_tblr_childs_total_tl }
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\NewChildSelector { subfive }
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {3} {5} { \l_tblr_childs_total_tl }
      {
        \clist_put_right:Nx \l_tblr_childs_clist
          {
            ##1, \int_eval:n {##1 + 1 }, \int_eval:n {##1 + 2 }, \int_eval:n {##1 + 3 }
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  rowhead = 1, cells = {c},
  hline{mainfive} = {0.05em,lightgray},
  hline{subfive} = {1-2,4-5}{0.03em,lightgray},
  hline{1,Z} = {0.08em,black}, % Z stands for the last
}
  Head & Head & Head & Head & Head \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
  a    & b    & c    & d    & e    \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the effort and solution, however my question is asking for a command. I will have to look into this tabularray package