# How to omit vertical realignment when using cmidrule in different colors in a `tabularx` environment?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am trying to create a table using the `tabularx` environment in Latex that includes various \cmidrule of different colors. However the lines created are not on the same vertical line (as seen in the screenshot below, the code is provided later in the question) :

[image: Table screenshot showing that the vertical alignment of \cmidrule of different colors is not respected]

I have found this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35821/301750) that gives a satisfactory result for tables in a `tabular`environment.
However, I have to use `\tabularx` in order to use a special column type I modified as well as column widths (see code).

```
% !TEX program = lualatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % For row coloring
\usepackage{tabularx}      % For the tabularx environment
\usepackage{colortbl}      % For coloring the rules
\usepackage{array}         % For adjusting column widths
\usepackage{booktabs}      % For better horizontal rules

% Vertical centering for 'X' type columns
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35821/301750
% Correct for \cmidrule colour adjustment/vertical skip
\newcommand{\corcmidrule}[1][2pt]{% \corcmidrule[<len>]
    \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-\belowrulesep-\aboverulesep-#1\relax]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    column 1 & column 2 & column 3 \\
    \cmidrule[2pt](lr){1-1}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{blue}%
    \cmidrule[2pt](lr){2-2}\corcmidrule\arrayrulecolor{black}%
    \cmidrule[2pt](lr){3-3}
    text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
    text & text & text\\ \cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){1-1}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){2-2}\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr){3-3}
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!5} % Alternate row colors
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Issue with vertical placement of cmidrule}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
        >{\hsize=1.1\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=0.8\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=1.2\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=1\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=1.3\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=0.7\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=1.4\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=1\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=0.5\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=0.8\hsize\centering}X
        >{\hsize=1.2\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X
    }
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}\toprule
    col 1 & col 2 & col 3 & col 4 & col 5 & col 6 & col 7 & col 8 & col 9 & col 10 & col 11 \\
    \arrayrulecolor{orange}\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){7-7}
        \arrayrulecolor{gray}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-6}\cmidrule(lr){8-8}
    content 1 & content 2 & content 3 & content 4 & content 5 & content 6 & content 7 & content 8 & content 9 & content 10 & content 11 \\
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I would assume that the issue lies in the use of '\\' in the `\corcmidrule` definition but I could not be sure at all...

I know the code does not show the `tabularx` table using the `\corcmidrule` but it just does not work. The `\corcmidrule` is used in the `tabular` environment to show the desired result.
I tried changing the code using a `\vspace` instead of `\\` but it does not fix it. I must agree, I do not really understand what the code does so I am asking for help.

Thanks in advance.

In case you cannot run the code: here are the two resulting tables :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your table, even if you in table use `\footnotesize` font size is bigger than defaults `article` size of the `\textwidth`. A remedy can be enlarge text block size by use `geometry` package.
- Writing your second table by use of the `tabularray` package is simple to get desired result.
- Beside this code is shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For row coloring
\usepackage{tabularray}      % For the tabularx environment
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}      % For better horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\footnotesize
    \caption{Issue with vertical placement of cmidrule}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{11}{X[c,m]}},
                 colsep  = 3pt,
                 row{even} = {gray!5}
                 }
    \toprule[fg=gray]
    col 1   & col 2     & col 3     & col 4     & col 5 & 
    col 6   & col 7     & col 8     & col 9     & col 10 & 
    col 11 \\
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=orange]{1-1}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=gray]{3-3}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=orange]{4-4}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=orange]{7-7}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=gray]{2-2}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=gray]{5-5}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=orange]{6-6}
    \cmidrule[lr, fg=gray]{8-8}
content 1   & content 2 & content 3 & content 4 & content 5     & 
content 6   & content 7 & content 8 & content 9 & content 10    & 
content 11 \\
    \bottomrule[fg=gray]
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, in my document I used another \documentclass that has a wider layout, sorry for the mistake... 
The packages you used seems very interesting but now I am tempted to change all of my table with it, oh well;)
Anyways thanks a lot I am going to have to play around with it. Did you learn about of this package using a particular resource?

Comment: @AlexJJoohn, transition from `tabularx` to `tabularray` is not so hard. Of course you need some time to learn some specific of it syntax, but package documentation is concise and thoroughly. Another possibilities is not use colored rules. To master it, you need to thoroughly  study `colortblr` package documentation. BTW, if you load `[table]{xcolor}˙you not need to load `colortbl` package. It is loaded by `table` option.